# How do I get IE8 to open a blank page with CTRL-N?

Tags: internet-explorer-8, session

When I used `CTRL-N` to open a new window with Firefox, it gives me a blank window (because I've set my start page to be blank).

How do I do the same thing with IE8? Using `CTRL-N` there opens a new window but it loads up the same page that was in the original window, even though the start page is set to `about:blank`.

This causes havoc when I'm on certain sites since those sites detect that I'm logged in twice and kick me out of *both* sessions.

Comment: it would be polite to keep the original question so others could make use of it. I suppose the question is 'what is the hotkey for starting a new session on ie8' ?

Comment: FWIW, there are [simple alternative ways to open a blank new window in IE](http://superuser.com/a/465029/138020), not with Ctrl+N.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, there is no setting to change the behavior of Ctrl-N.

What you want is done in IE with another command - also under "File" - called "New Session".

But then unfortunately, it seems as though IE 8's "New Session" feature does not have a hotkey.
Well, we can fix that with a separate hotkey program.

- Download [AutoHotkey](http://autohotkey.com)
- Use this script:

```
#IfWinActive ahk_class IEFrame
^n::Run, %PROGRAMFILES%\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe,,max
#IfWinActive
```

Comment: Awesome. That worked wonders. I removed the ",,max" but that's just a personal preference. Both the class and the path were still correct for IE8. Thanks.

Comment: Yeah I checked them before writing :) No problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you run Internet Explorer with the `-nomerge` switch, each new window won't share the session data from the previous window when launched from that shortcut.

Additionally, if you go to `File->New Session` this will open a new window with your default home page.

[More Info](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/05/06/session-cookies-sessionstorage-and-ie8.aspx)

Comment: "-merge" didn't seem to help, it still opened the same web page. And I was looking for a fast shortcut. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This is awesome! Too bad there is no keyboard shortcut (by default - I saw the hints below). Does Firefox have this functionality? On the other side this is not the same as opening a new window with blank page. For that I used this workaround: open new tab, move the tab with mouse out of the window to become own window. ctrl-N opening a copy of the previous page is really silly (and not configurable on top of that, in what scenario would one want that behavior?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new shortcut of iexplore.exe on the desktop and edit its shortcut key proprieties to CTRL+ALT+N, now CTRL+ALT+N will open a new IE window.

Comment: Strange. I couldn't actually change the shortcut in properties. Don't know if that's a corporate lock-down thing or something else. Thanks anyway.

Comment: just press "N" in that field

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 7, move IE to the first app in the task bar (if not already), press Windows + Shift + 1.