# How do I open a blank new window in IE9 instead of a copy of the current window?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get IE8 to open a blank page with CTRL-N?](https://superuser.com/questions/69857/how-do-i-get-ie8-to-open-a-blank-page-with-ctrl-n)

I'm stuck using IE9 at a workstation at work and would like to know what setting do I have to change so that I **don't** open a copy of the page I am on when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>. I already have it set to open blank tabs, but that does not effect new windows.

Comment: Can you clarify if you want a new window or new tab. You have referred to both in your question.

Comment: @amiregelz I saw that, but I was hoping IE9 would have a setting to change. I don't think it is a duplicate as this is asking about the next version.

Comment: @CyberSkull You're right, actually there are easier ways than binding a hotkey or using a script; see my answer.

Comment: The accepted answer here is much clearer than in the "duplicate"..... in the other it looks like everyone is ignoring the question, when in fact there is no builtin option, as explained clearly here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't make the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> open a blank new window instead of a copy of the current window in IE9, but here are 3 alternative ways to open a blank new IE9 window:

1. Right-click an IE icon, and select "Internet Explorer".
2. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+Left-click on an IE icon.
3. Middle-click on an IE icon.

Answer (score 0):

You did not clarify in your question if you want a window or a tab. You have referred to both in your question.

So I searched for both, but could not find a keyboard shortcut to open a new "blank" window. You can however use <kbd>Ctl</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab which loads your home page. In your case it will be blank.