# IE10: How to open a new window without duplicating the current page using the keyboard?

Tags: windows-7, keyboard-shortcuts, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-10

I used to use CTRL+N in other browsers like Google Chrome or FireFox to open a new window. However, if I do this in IE10 in my Win7, a new window is opened but the current URL is reopened in this window too. This can take several seconds, but I just need to open a new blank window.

I know, I can do that using the mouse (see [How do I open a blank new window in IE9 instead of a copy of the current window?](https://superuser.com/questions/464984/how-do-i-open-a-blank-new-window-in-ie9-instead-of-a-copy-of-the-current-window)), but is there a way to do it using the keyboard? Do not want to touch mouse every time when I'm working mainly with the keyboard.

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser. There was already a [solution](http://superuser.com/a/69860/191912) for your problem. The answer from Revolter may also help you (and even without 3rd party software).

Comment: @techie007, it was really hard to find that answer as I different terms are used for the same problem. And I didn't mean only CTRL+N - any keyboard combination is good to do the desired task.

Comment: @Tim, I liked the "fix" with setting CTRL+ALT+N for the IE shortcut. It seems, I needed to specify that I do not want to use external tools like AutoHotKey to solve the task.